# test requirements for published npm packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npmjs

I publish some rudimentary JavaScript packages in [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/) mainly for the convenience of importing them from my projects wherever I may need them.

One of them (a minmax engine with alpha-beta pruning), let's call it `package-foo`, may be useful to a broader audience.

My question has to do with the expectations around tests. If somebody clones the gihtub repo of the package, they will be able to run `npm test` (to run the [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) tests) or `npm run flow` (for static type analysis using [Flow](https://flow.org/)). However, when they install my package using `npm` to use it in one of their own projects (by listing it in their `package.json` file), they are not able to `cd` to the `node_modules/package-foo` directory and successfully run `npm test` there.

Is it a requirement / best practice that tests for a package can be executed from the `node_modules` sub-directory or are tests meant to work only in a development setting (i.e. in a cloned github repo)?

Experimenting a little with packages that I see in my own `node_modules` directory I found **none** where I was able to successfully run `npm test`. What are best practices / expectations of user programmers in this area?

Comment: I would not expect to be able to run `npm test` on anything in `node_modules`. If someone wants to test a package, they need to test using the source (which is usually on Github)

Comment: It's nice when you've run into a bug on a system and the tests work though!